# Turning an integer into excess notation using binary

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a python program that will allow me to turn an integer into excess notation. I prompt the user for the bit length as well as the integer that they want to be turned into excess notation. I would like the excess representation to be put in a list that can then be printed out. Im having trouble figuring out how to go about both turning the basic binary form into excess, as well as putting that into a list. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @manetsus I don't know of a package that does it. Do you? You could share!

Comment: Do you have a specific number of bits and is zero padding expected?

Comment: @tdelaney Obviously not! I asked the question to the OP, not other! It seemed to me that OP has lack of research work. That's why I left such question. Thanks.

Comment: So basically my idea is that I take the length that the user gives me and then I make a list full of zeros of that length. Then I compare the excess value to the list, and change the list so that it is the same as the excess notation. Then I print the list. Not sure how to go about that

Comment: A list with an entry for each bit? That seems like more work than needed. Does my answer look like what you want?

Comment: You're example is great, but i have to do it this way for an assignment. I agree, its more work than needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a bit of string manipulation. Take the absolute value of the number, use string formatting to convert to a binary string and then tack a 0 or 1 on the front depending on whether its + or -. This example does 16 bits

```
>>> val=-100
>>> '{:d}{:016b}'.format(val < 0, abs(val))
'00000000001100100'
>>> val=100
>>> '{:d}{:016b}'.format(val < 0, abs(val))
'10000000001100100'
```

Comment: Slightly more Pythonic: `'{:d}{:016b}'.format(val < 0, abs(val))`

Comment: @MikeDeSimone I like that... changed.